# Fixed Memory I don't need to allocate?

Tags: windows

I just need a fixed address in any win32 process, where I can store 8 bytes without using any winapi function. I also cannot use assembler prefixes like fs:. and I have no stack pointer.

What I need:
-8 bytes of memory
-constant address and present in any process
-read and write access (via pointer, from the same process)
-should not crash the application (at least not instantly) if modified.

Don't even ask, why I need it.

Comment: Now that you mention it, I'm interested in why you need it...(and why this is also tagged with internet-explorer and firefox)

Comment: The only address that is fixed is that of KUSER_SHARED_DATA, which unfortunately you cannot write to. But I don't see the problem with simply guessing where things such as the PEB/TEBs are - this doesn't sound legitimate anyway.

Comment: i just use 0x10000 now. It is present quite often, because it is the first page above the 64k null pointer region. but my code still crashes about 50% of time. however it works (sometimes).
@wj32: could you give me a pointer?

Comment: This is bogus.  You shouldn't be doing this.  If you really want help, open a new question with your actual problem.

Comment: @Floste: KUSER_SHARED_DATA is at 0x7ffe0000 (which you could've found by some Googling...) (unless I misunderstood your question)

Comment: I just did a +1 to balance the -1 to the question. There's nothing wrong with the question.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I'm aware of to do this is to use a DLL with a shared section...

```
// This goes in a DLL loaded by all apps that want to share the data
#pragma data_seg (".sharedseg")
long long myShared8Bytes = 0; // has to be initialized or this fails
#pragma data_seg()
```

Then, you add the following to the link command for the dll:

```
/SECTION:sharedseg,RWS
```

I am also curious why you want this...

Comment: And what exactly makes you think that `myShared8Bytes` will have the same address in every process?

Comment: @Ben Voigt: I guess I should have explained more.  You don't need the address when you do this.  You link to the DLL and myShared8Bytes is seen as a global variable.  So even if the DLL does load at different addresses in different processes, this will still work.  This mechanism is used to make global hooks work in Windows, so...

Comment: Floste has now clarified that he doesn't want shared memory.  It sounds as if he is loading a hook into multiple processes, probably via a buffer overrun exploit or similar, and wants some scratch space it can use while it runs.  The fixups done by the linker to compensate for a library loading at a non-preferred address, won't be done for an injected hook.

Comment: In that case...  He's screwed. :).  There's no guarantee I can think of in Windows that anything will be at any fixed address especially is ASLR is involved.  Though, at one point, I think Richter posted a way to inject code into another process without using any stack...  But I cannot find it.

Comment: "probably via a buffer overrun exploit or similar, and wants some scratch space it can use while it runs."   exaktly. But ist actually a heap overrun that allows to overwrite an int32 with an int64. but there is still a check wether it writes behind the actual buffer, so a classic exploit doesn't work. but the bufer may contain multiple vars e.g. a pointer i control just after the int32. And because it is in some scripting language there a lots of restrictions and there is no way of converting a pointer to a int32 (unless i find another bug). and i have only one try.

Answer (score 1):

Not that I recommend this, but the PEB probably has some unused or inconsequential fields in it that you could overwrite.  I still think this is a terrible idea, though.

Comment: The PEB isn't at a fixed address.

Comment: It is fixed for a given platform/version.  Of course this is an implementation detail and subject to change at any time, so obviously it is not a good approach.  Though I suppose that is true for anything we could come up with, so I don't think there is a reliable answer to the question.

Comment: No. For example, as I'm typing this I'm looking at firefox.exe which has its PEB at 0x7ffd8000, and winamp.exe which has its PEB at 0x7ffd3000. Especially with ASLR, the kernel wouldn't want the PEB to be loaded at a fixed address in every process.

Comment: Ah, you are right.  Looks like PEB randomization was introduced in XP SP2.  This just proves the point that relying on implementation details is a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

> constant address and present in any
>   process

You won't be able to achieve that. Win32 uses paged memory so different processes can access the *same* memory addresses even though it is different memory.

Comment: i don't need it to be the same memory. And i also do not need to share it across processes. it just has to be allocated.